# Rails n elements before last

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails I often do this:

```
Model.last(5).first
```

This retrieves element *last*-5.

Is there a built-in way of doing this?

Comment: how do you sort by default?

Comment: Normally just by id... does it matter?

Comment: there were 'issues' because depending on the ORM, the default sort is not the same and some people didn't undrstand why on local and on dev, behaviour changed

Answer (score 1):

The more common way is offset()

```
Model.offset(5).last
```

Edit (for lazy people):

```
1.8.7 :001 > User.first.id
 => 1 
1.8.7 :002 > User.last.id
 => 143455 
1.8.7 :003 > User.offset(5).last.id
 => 143450
```

Comment: this is wrong, you have to reverse the order of selection first, hence my question

Comment: You dont have to reverse this grabs the last 5th element!

Comment: maybe you can read this better here than in doc: `Client.limit(5).offset(30) will return instead a maximum of 5 clients` ***beginning with the 31st***

Comment: Do i talk about limit + offset?

Comment: Jep and i dont get what you want from me

Comment: actually nothing, keep your wrong answer, it's not my business

Comment: last attempt: OP want last-5, so if he has 30 records, he wants the 25th. your solution will give him the 6th.

Comment: ... iam returning the 5th last element. I will edit my post, you seem to be to lazy to test it yourself...

Comment: If you had 30 entries, you'd return elements from 5 to 30 (25 elements). So yes the last one is the last one, still not what is expected here... Was my last comment here

Comment: I returned the last 5th element, witch was wanted here. And i proved it with an code example, why do you deleted it? Do you have tryd it out yourself? Instead of accepting my answer or prove me that iam wrong you tell over and over the same ... Your to proud to accept that you are incorrect? Or why do you deleted my code example?